# JavaScript: Returning a property of an object

Tags: javascript

I am doing a challenge from freeCodeCamp called "Profile Lookup". My problem seems to be that I cannot return the value of a property within an object. I am using dot notation, but have also tried using bracket notation.

The objective is to create a function that loops through an array of objects, `contacts`, to find whether a given `firstName` is within said array and whether that object contains a given `prop`.

If both the `firstName` and the `prop` exist, we have to return the value of the property.

If the `firstName` is found but `prop` is not, then we return "No such property".

If `firstName` is not found, we return "No such contact".

This is my code:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
    for(var i = 0; i<contacts.length; i++){
      if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return contacts.prop; 
        else 
          return "No such property"; 
      }
      else
        return "No such contact"; 
    }

// Only change code above this line
}
```

This is the array of objects that it is supposed to loop through:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];
```

EDIT: I must have dropped the [i] in `return contacts[i].prop` when I changed to bracket notation and then back to dot notation. Even when I reapply it, I am getting the same problem. Here is the updated function:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
    for(var i = 0; i<contacts.length; i++){
      if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return contacts[i].prop; 
        else 
          return "No such property"; 
      }
      else
        return "No such contact"; 
    }

// Only change code above this line
}
```

Comment: Your code correctly tests `contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` but then attempts to return `contacts.prop`. It should be `contacts[i][prop]`.

Comment: You `return` too early in that outer `else` case. You can only state to have found no such contact after having iterated all of them.

Comment: @Pointy I modified it to `return contacts[i].prop;` but I am still getting the same error. I also tried the bracket notation version which you provided.

Comment: @Matt there's a big difference between `contacts[i][prop]` and `contacts[i].prop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return the value of the variable as key

```
return contact[i][prop];
```

By doing `contacts[i].prop` you are returning the attribute named `prop`: `contact[i]['prop']`

**Complet Function**

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
    for(var i = 0; i<contacts.length; i++){
      if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return contacts[i][prop]; 
        else 
          return "No such property"; 
      }
      else
        return "No such contact"; 
    }

// Only change code above this line
}
```

Also you're returning for every case something the first iteration.. Even if the name is later on the array. Let's try something

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {   
    // Try to find the right contact
    for(var i = 0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
      // Name is found
      if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName){ 
        // Return prop if exist, or error message
        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return contacts[i][prop]; 
        else 
          return "No such property"; 
      } 
    }
    // No one with this name is found, return error
    return "No such contact";
}
```

My way to do it  (not tested)

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {   
    let contact = null
    // Try to find the right contact
    contacts.forEach(c => {
      if (!contact && c && c.firstName && c.firstName == firstname) {
        contact = c
      }
    })

    if (!contact)
      return "No such contact";
    return contact.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contact[prop] : "No such property"
}
```

Comment: Your code worked; I am not sure exactly why but think it has something to do with what you said here:  "Also you're returning for every case something the first iteration.. Even if the name is later on the array."

What did you mean here? Because if the if statement failed, it was still returning something? But it would return something ultimately anyway, no? The only difference I see is the return is placed outside the for loop in the example you provided after "Let's try something".

Comment: Okay, so look the first function i wrote on this reply. When you iterate the list of contacts: You start with `i=0`. If the first contact have the good name, it work fine. But if the first contact haven't the right name, it automatically return the "No such contact". You never looking for others contacts (i=1, i=2, ..). So you have to look every contacts and return something only if you found the right contact, and you will go at the end of the funciton only when no contact are found with this name (so you return at the end the "No such contact")

Comment: Ahh! I see now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to ear that :)